# How to use Rails3.2.6's send_data to display an image Active Record in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There are several questions about `send_data` in SO, but the answers can not resolve mine.

I am practicing the Chapter 21's views of [Agile Web Development with Rails 4](https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4), when using `send_data` to display a image Active Record in the browser, I did not get the result as p351, but a error relative to `send_data` in development.log :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:17:in `picture'
```

But, I can get the right result through `send_file` with the same `data` .

The things I finished as follows:
(1) my environment is: ruby-1.9.3, rails 3.2.6
(2) table file: `app/db/migrate/xxx_create_pictures.rb`

```
 create_table :pictures do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :content_type
    t.binary :data
 end
```

here, `t.binary :data` is used to store image's data
(3) controller file: `app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb`:

```
def picture
   @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
   send_data(@pciture.data,
          filename: @picture.name,
          type: @picture.content_type,
          disposition: "inline")
end
```

(4)when accessing `http://localhost:3000/pictures/1`, the filename and the type can be displayed in the browser but the image, and got a error 
as described above. Also, if I use `send_file` as follows, the image can be displayed:

```
file = "my_file.png"
File.open(file, "wb"){ |f| f << @picture.data }
send_file( file, :type => 'image/png' )
```

Of course, `send_file` has a unhappy result that it will save a unnecessary file `my_file.png`

I don't why and what things I miss? Any advice will be appreciated!

EDIT: I am sorry to ask such a question. As @Deep said, I wrote a wrong word `pciture`!

Comment: correct your typo in the code and try. `send_data(@pciture.data,` to `send_data(@picture.data,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined method 'data' for nil:NilClass` always means that it is trying to do `nil.data` which is not a defined method for `nil`. So it throws this error. I have seen in the community many of the users post this error. So this just means that the object on which you are trying to use the method is `nil` due to some reason. So first check that why it is `nil`. There may be reasons such as typo or finding some wrong value or anything. The answer to you question is to correct a typo:

```
send_data(@pciture.data
```

to

```
send_data(@picture.data
```